# how to get time-speed function from distance-speed function, numerical?

Tags: calculus, numerical-calculus

I have speed function depends on distance. Actually, numerical connection.
$v = v(s)$, so i have $[ s_i, v_i ]$ values. But I want to get speed function depens on time ( $v=v(t)$ )

time and distance:
$ s = s_0+\int_{0}^t v(t)dt $

how to get numerical values of $[t_i, v_i]$

note: there no problem with numerical integral and differantiation.

EDIT:
I have tried this matlab script for $t = t_0 + \int_{0}^s {1 \over v(s)}ds$ (came from ${ds \over dt} = v$)

```
s = linspace(0,400); % I will determinate for this set.
v = V_s(s);  % V_s(s) function is not aritmatical but interpolation function.
% I have [s, v] numerical values. 

t = zeros(size(s));
for i=1:length(t)-1;
    upper = ( s(i+1)-s(i) ) / v(i+1); % ds/v
    lower = ( s(i+1)-s(i) ) / v(i); % ds/v
    %may be correct finite differantial element is:
    correct = ( upper + lower ) / 2;
    %my t values, with numerical integration
    t(i+1) = t(i) + correct;
end

%now, I have [s, t] numerical values.
%i can touch [v(s), t], so [v, t] numerical values

plot(s,v); %distance-speed graph
plot(t,v); %time-speed graph
```

Comment: Do you know $v(s)$'s function? I ask because if it has a finite set of derivatives w/respect to $s$ then you could just progress $s$ and $v$ and log the time while doing so.

Comment: I have not got analytical $v(s)$ function. But I can know $v(s_0)$ for any $s_0$ values because i am using interpolation.  
I have tried this, i guess it works:

$ds/dt=v(s)$ ,    

$\int{ds\over v(s)} = \int dt$  ,     

$t = t_0 + \int_{s_0}^s {1\over v(s)}ds$  ,     

Therefore, i have $t_i$ numerical values for $s_i$'s. Then i know $[t_i(s_i), v_i(s_i)]$ for $s_i$

Comment: Makes sense to me. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I ve added on edit

Comment: I'll probably check it out this evening. You should do this to get the time and velocity set, then cubic spline the time and position, then do finite differences to see how they compare. It's not a very structured way to check, but it's great to know if you're in the ball park or not